# Issues with setting up models

Tags: gazebo-model

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I want to clone the models repository on my system, so I followed this step from the documentation:
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models

This gives the error:
abort: error: _ssl.c:510: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number

Okay, then I opened Gazebo gui and opened the Insert tab. Which shows the following messages:
/home/xxx/.gazebo/models
/usr/share/gazebo-6.5/models
Connecting to model database...

And, nothing else. I don't think it is able to connect to the models database.

I'm working behind a proxy. Is there a way for gazebo to use these proxy settings?

Or, bypassing all this, can I simply download the models from my browser, without Mercurial or anything else? Why such a roundabout way for downloading models?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12308/issues-with-setting-up-models/) by [sanjeevmk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2394/sanjeevmk/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can download the models as a zip [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/downloads)

---

Originally posted by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) with karma: 768 on 2016-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0